# Trying to join 3 tables

Tags: mysql

This doubt is long as I dont know how to explain this,but its very simple
I have 3 tables

1.Master table with all details of the customers with

```
CID(P.KEY)     C_NAME        C_CLASS     C_PLACE
=================================================
1      ,       XYZ      ,     CS     ,     INDIA
```

2.Resource table with

```
--------------------------------------------------
CR_ID(P.KEY)    C_ID(F1)     PRIMARY_CLASS_GUIDE(F3)   SECONDARY_CLASS_GUIDE
============================================================================ 
1       ,         1         ,       1              ,          2
```

3.Student table with

```
-----------------------------------------------------
S_ID(P.Key)      S_NAME       S_CONTACT
=================================================
1          ,       abc    ,       000 

2         ,        cde     ,      000
```

All these 3 tables are interconnected:

1.When I select the class from table 1,I match it to `C_ID` from table 2 and get the values of `PRIMARY_CLASS_GUIDE` and `SECONDARY_CLASS_GUIDE`

2.`PRIMARY_CLASS_GUIDE` and `SECONDARY_CLASS_GUIDE` is referring to table 3 `S_ID`.

I tried running query in different ways but since `PRIMARY_CLASS_GUIDE` AND `SECONDARY_CLASS_GUIDE` is in the same table,I'm confused in how to use this in "SELECT" statement

```
select table1.C_Name,tabl1.C_Place,Table2.A_name as 
'PRIMARY_CLASS_GUIDE',Table2.A_name as 'SECONDARY_CLASS_GUIDE'
from `table1` as `table1`,`table2` as  `table2`,`table3` as `table3` 
where 
table1.C_ID = table2.C_ID and table2.PRIMARY_CLASS_GUIDE=table3.S_ID and Table1.C_Class='CS'
```

OUTPUT needed is:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
C_NAME   C_PLACE    PRIMARY_CLASS_GUIDE    SECONDARY_CLASS_GUIDE 
=================================================================
xyz  ,      INDIA    ,     abc           ,        cde
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could two inner join on table student

```
select m.C_Name, m.C_Place, s1.A_name as  'PRIMARY_CLASS_GUIDE',s2.A_name as 'SECONDARY_CLASS_GUIDE'
from  Master as m
inner join Resource r ON  m.cid = r.c_id
inner join Student s1  ON r.PRIMARY_CLASS_GUIDE = s1._id
inner join Student s2 ON r.SECONDARY_CLASS_GUIDE= s2._id
```

Comment: hi,Thank you
But the SECONDARY_CLASS_GUIDE is not being displayed at all

Comment: answer  update  ...  with .SECONDARY_CLASS_GUIDE= s2._id

Answer (score 1):

You can try below - you need to join with multiple instances of table3

```
select t1.C_Name,t1.C_Place,
       t3.S_name as 'PRIMARY_CLASS_GUIDE',
       t4.S_name as 'SECONDARY_CLASS_GUIDE'
from table2 t2 inner join table1 as t1 on t1.C_ID = t2.C_ID
inner join table3 t3 on t2.PRIMARY_CLASS_GUIDE=t3.S_ID
inner join table3 t4 on t2.SECONDARY_CLASS_GUIDE=t4.S_ID
```

NOTE: it's always better to use explicit join rather comma separated join